# addClass blinks on window scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I add some class to a link when its target is visible in window. But when I click that link the class is added, then removed, then added again which creates undesirable "blinking" effect. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/inliner/gx7ocfhr/6/ explains it all better. Scroll a little, then click one of three items in header.
What am I doing wrong here? How do I prevent this blinking?

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
  return ((elemTop - docViewTop)<= 240) && ((elemBottom - 70) >= docViewTop);
}    
$(window).scroll(function(){
  isScrolledIntoView("#advertizers") ? $(".s1").addClass("active") : $(".s1").removeClass("active");
  isScrolledIntoView("#traders") ? $(".s2").addClass("active") : $(".s2").removeClass("active");
  isScrolledIntoView("#agencies") ? $(".s3").addClass("active") : $(".s3").removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$(window).scroll` handler is fired during `animate()` function. try re-binding it in the `animate()` callback. check this

http://jsfiddle.net/f8jjcspt/1/

**Edit**: also LukeThompson suggestion is more efficient

Comment: Thanks Ahmad! This works just fine. So the idea is to scroll first, then change the class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the scroll event firing on the anchor click, a possible solution would be to add a flag, like isAnchorScroll, define and set this to false inside your $(document).ready(function(){
In $(window).scroll event check your flag and if true return before changing the class, set your flag to true inside your anchorScroll function and then set to false in your animation callback. You will also want to call $(window).trigger('scroll') in the animation callback. Hope this helps